# Trying to select from foreach in foreach loop

Tags: c#, sql, select, foreach, webmatrix

i am trying to select results from earlier selection like this:

```
foreach(var ld in db.Query(query, start, end)){  
                <tr>
                   <td colspan="0">ld.ConID</td>
                </tr>
                foreach(var payment in db.Query(payments, ld.ConID, start, end))
                {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@payment.ConID</td>
                            <td>@payment.TransID</td>
                            <td>@payment.Amount</td>
                            <td>@payment.Date</td>
                        </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
        }
```

It doesnt return any error but i dont get what i want ?!

Its just prints ld.ConID variable ... like this:

```
LD11102220111
LD11020212330
LD13101011123
```

While i expect a table something like:

```
LD1102201333
LD1102201333 | 1380932109889 | 30.00 | 01/02/2014
LD1102201333 | 1380932109890 | 12.00 | 01/02/2014
LD1102201333 | 1380932109891 | 24.00 | 01/02/2014

LD1102201334
LD1102201334 | 1380932109892 | 25.00 | 03/02/2014
LD1102201334 | 1380932109893 | 122.00 | 02/02/2014
LD1102201334 | 1380932109894 | 32.00 | 01/02/2014

...
..
.
```

Can you please help me in this case?

Comment: I don`t know how to do it because i have to parse parameters ... any suggestions ???

Comment: If i declare it out of the loop it returns error saying "it doesnt exist in this context" ... there are alot of duplicates in the ConID

Answer (score 0):

Looks like  db.Query(payments, ld.ConID, start, end) is not returning any values. 
* check the 'payments' variable value.

Good luck..